# How to get avc logging ( selinux ) in Android working?

Tags: root-access, security, kernel, selinux, bind-mount

I am on Android 10. Whether I `setenforce 0 or 1-` I cannot get `avc  ( aka SeLinux )`  errors logged. I checked   `ramoops` files also and its ditto.

```
root@m20lte:/ # setenforce 1                                                                                                         
root@m20lte:/ # grep -i avc /proc/kmsg                                                                                               
<6>[358888.761197]  [3: servicemanager: 3452] avc:  received setenforce notice (enforcing=1)
<6>[358890.709988]  [2:           init:    1] avc:  received setenforce notice (enforcing=1)
<6>[358901.864803]  [0:hwservicemanage: 3453] avc:  received setenforce notice (enforcing=1)
^C
root@m20lte:/ # logcat -d | grep -i "avc"                                                                                            
07-14 08:31:21.858  3452  3452 E audit   : avc:  received setenforce notice (enforcing=1)
07-14 08:31:23.806     1     1 E audit   : avc:  received setenforce notice (enforcing=1)
07-14 08:31:34.962  3453  3453 E audit   : avc:  received setenforce notice (enforcing=1)
```

I'd like to understand `avc denials` that are supposed to be logged when  `setenforce 0` is on so I can understand what changes to make to `sePolicy` to get  my exceptions incorporated .  Is that going to be any easy ride or a long shot ? In the above  box , besides just `setenforce`  notice it should have  logged in a bunch of messages  as I ran  various apps that would trigger `avc` exceptions